# Django - loop using models.PositiveIntegerField variable

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have this code:

```
class Zapas(models.Model):
tym_domaci = models.ForeignKey(Tym, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
tym_hoste = models.ForeignKey(Tym, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
datum = models.DateTimeField('datum zapasu')
goly_domaci = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
goly_hoste = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

for x in range (goly_domaci):
    strelec = models.ForeignKey(Hrac, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={Hrac.tym == tym_domaci})
    nahraval = models.ForeignKey(Hrac, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={Hrac.tym == tym_domaci})

for x in range (goly_hoste):
    strelec = models.ForeignKey(Hrac, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={Hrac.tym == tym_hoste})
    nahraval = models.ForeignKey(Hrac, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={Hrac.tym == tym_hoste})
```

What i am trying to do, is to load all the players that scored a goal and players that assisted on it (if there is any) for each team. Problem is, that i cannot use goly_domaci and goly_hoste in the for loop because they are PositiveIntegerField and not an Integer. Is there any way to convert the PositiveIntegerField into Integer? Or can I even use the for loop like this? I am new to python and Django so I really dont know how to solve it. Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1):

No that is not the reason. This code doesn't make sense; you can't define fields dynamically like that. Fields depend on columns in the database, a model must have a fixed number of fields. And `goly_domaci` is itself a field, it doesn't have a value at this point; it only has a value when accessed from an actual instance, at which point it's far too late to be defining other fields.

But this isn't what you want to do anyway. There is no point defining all those separate foreign keys to the same target model. What you want to do is define a separate model for Goals, which points to this model (I assume Zapas means Game).

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Zapas)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Tym, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    strelec = models.ForeignKey(Hrac, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nahraval = models.ForeignKey(Hrac, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then you can drop your `goly_domaci` and `goly_hoste` fields altogether, as you can calculate them when you need to display them:

```
goly_hoste = my_zpas.goal_set.filter(team=my_zpas.tym_hoste).count()
goly_domaci = my_zpas.goal_set.filter(team=my_zpas.tym_domaci).count()
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.
Yes, zapas = game, sorry I didnt realize that I am not using english words for variables. And to your answer, I actually wanted to avoid using another class, because I wanted to define all the goals when creating new Game(zapas). 
Your solution means, that i will create new entry Game, defining how many goals were scored by each team and saving it. Then create new entry Goal for every goal scored in that game. Am i right?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why you wanted to avoid a separate class, that is the best way of modelling this kind of data.